# mysql slow_log logs queries longer than long_query_time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having a very strange situation in which i have mysql version 5.5.46 working with engine innoDB.
I have enables slow_log and long_query_time is set on 3 seconds,
and although i have in the slow log queries that finished with in less than 0.5 second and more queries such as selects/updates and inserts that finish with in 0.000037 seconds.

```
# Query_time: 0.002699  Lock_time: 0.000037 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
```

I checked weather i have enabled the parameter log_queries_not_using_indexes but it is OFF.

I tried to disable slow-log set in to off then on.
I tried on setting the long_query_time to 10 seconds but it does not help the issue.

Restart is not an option currently on a production system.

I searched everywhere for solution, the only thing i can think on is to set the global variable: min_examined_row_limit to more than 1 since almost all of the queries that finish with in less than 1 second examine only 1 row, but i would not want that because it may hide problems later.

### Some of the logs for example:

```
INSERT INTO xxx (X values);
# Time: 170521  9:47:46
# Query_time: 0.006520  Lock_time: 0.000041 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1495374466;

UPDATE 'schema_name'.'replication_heartbeat' SET ts='2017-05-21T09:47:46.000720', file='test-db44-bin.089771', position='10638144', relay_master_log_file=NULL, exec_master_log_pos=NULL WHERE server_id='44';
# Time: 170521  9:47:47
# Query_time: 0.014305  Lock_time: 0.000043 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1495374467;

UPDATE 'schema_name'.'replication_heartbeat' SET ts='2017-05-21T09:47:47.000700', file='test-db44-bin.089771', position='10760016', relay_master_log_file=NULL, exec_master_log_pos=NULL WHERE server_id='44';
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to remove all that junk from the  slow log?

Thanks everyone,
Leon.

Comment: How about your `log_queries_not_using_indexes` server system variable?

Comment: I tried it and it is marked as OFF, and still i have those records in the slow log that took less than a 0.5 sconds.

Comment: could you post the result of `show global variable like '%log_queries_not_using_indexes%'` ?

Comment: yes sure, this is the output of the command:
log_queries_not_using_indexes OFF